# Did the Catholic Church ever prescribe a single unified text of the Lord's Prayer to be said on all occasions by all the faithful?

Tags: catholicism, translation, lords-prayer

Over a period of time, one comes across  versions of the Lord's Prayer each worded in a unique manner. There appears to be slight inconsistency among the texts of the Prayer one is taught in Catechism, that said during the Holy Mass and the Prayer  said at home or in private.

Of course, the Lord said " Pray like this" when he taught the disciples to pray (Mtt 6:9-13).  A little bit of inconsistency in the Prayers said during various occasions, and by people belonging to  different cultures  is therefore, understandable. For instance:

> Our Father in heaven Vs Abba Father in heaven

> Hallowed be they name Vs Holy be your  name.

> Give us today our daily bread Vs Give us this day our daily bread

> Forgive us our sins Vs Forgive us our trespasses

> As we forgive those who sin against us Vs As we have forgiven those who sin against us

> Bring us not into temptation Vs Do not let us fall into temptation

> Deliver from evil Vs Deliver us from the evil one

Would it not, however, be beautiful if the faithful all across the world recited the Lord's Prayer following one single unified text ? My question therefore is: Did the Catholic Church ever prescribe a single unified  text of the  Lord's Prayer to be said on all occasions by all the faithful ?

Comment: Is this is an English-only question? Of course there are different versions in different languages. For the same language this is less obvious.

Comment: The faithful have one universal prescribed text for the Lord's Prayer and it begins "Pater noster..."

Comment: Thanks K-HB . Even within the same language one can notice the difference. Some like the senior ones prefer to use the old translations while the younger generation go for the  modern versions.  For instance, in my Southern Indian language, the Prayer was originally   translated from Syriac and began with something like Our Father in the heavens ....In personal prayer the above-80 age group still use that old version. The younger generation however prefers the text translated from other languages like English.

Comment: Thanks,  jaredad7.  Pater noster is in fact,  the Latin translation, whereas the prayer taught by Jesus was in Aramaic and which got written down in Hebrew and Greek. And translation always comes at  a price !

Comment: @KadalikattJosephSibichan of course Pater Noster is the translation into Latin, but it is the universally prescribed version of the text for Catholics. It's the template from which other translations are to be derived.

Comment: Question is too broad.